# Posting to the Facebook Wall via ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, actionscript

I am trying to post something onto the user's wall. However I keep getting this error.

> TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
>       at com.facebook.graph.core::AbstractFacebook/handleRequestLoad()
>       at com.facebook.graph.net::AbstractFacebookRequest/dispatchComplete()
>       at com.facebook.graph.net::AbstractFacebookRequest/handleDataLoad()
>       at com.facebook.graph.net::AbstractFacebookRequest/handleURLLoaderComplete()
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>       at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Here is the code:

```
public function PostToUserWall(userId:String, message:String, name:String, caption:String, description:String, link:String):void
    {
        var params: Object = new Object;
        params.message = message;
        params.name = name;
        params.caption = caption;
        params.description = description;
        params.link = link;
        params.picture = "www.something.com/something.png";
        Facebook.api("/"+userId+"/feed", null, params, "POST");
    }
```

I am trying to understand what this problem is. But somehow cant figure it out. Any help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a challenge debugging with only a stack trace to go on. Posting code will improve the likelihood of somebody being able to help you. However, it looks to me like the callback `parameter` for your call to the Facebook API is not a function. I'd suggest you double check the parameters you're passing in the API call.

**Edit:**

The second parameter of the call to the facebook API should be a function which the API will execute when the result is returned. Try updating your code as follows:

```
public function PostToUserWall(userId:String, message:String, name:String, caption:String, description:String, link:String):void
{
        var params: Object = new Object;
        params.message = message;
        params.name = name;
        params.caption = caption;
        params.description = description;
        params.link = link;
        params.picture = "www.something.com/something.png";
        Facebook.api("/"+userId+"/feed", resultHandler, params, "POST");
}

private function resultHandler():void
{
    trace("Result!");
}
```

Comment: Guessed that net.uk.sweet!!! Just had done that and the problem is no longer there :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods that should work:

This one posts a bitmap from your swf.

```
public function postImageToUserWall(bmp:Bitmap, caption:String):void
{
    Facebook.api(_userID +'/photos', onPicPostedToUserWall, {message:caption, image:bmp, fileName:'file.png'}, URLRequestMethod.POST);
}

private function onPicPostedToUserWall(result:Object, fail:Object):void
{
    if (result)
    {
        //result.id is id of photo that was just posted - used to link to pic when posting to recipient's wall
    }
    else if (fail)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

This one posts a picture from a link:

```
public function postLinkToFeed(params:Object)
{
    Facebook.ui('feed', {   
                            name: params.name, 
                            caption: params.caption, 
                            description: params.description, 
                            picture: params.imageURL, 
                            link: params.link,
                            to: params.toID,
                            from: params.fromID
                        }, onPostToFeedComplete, 'iframe');
    }

private function onPostToFeedComplete(result:Object)
{
    //
}
```